# DOB is not saving in customer Account

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, magento2.3.3

In Customer Account DoB is not saving and giving Error like Please enter a valid date.

For reference please find the attached image.[image]

Thanks in Advance
Somu N

Comment: I think the `value` dob attribute is empty

Comment: No We are giving value eventhough it is throughing this error